# Login y redirección mediante Session en PHP/MySQLI

Tags: php, mysqli, formularios

Buenas comunidad de SO estoy buscando la solución mas segura para este tipo de login.

Lo que deseo es que por ejemplo que un administrador vaya a panel.php y el usuario a home.php

Codigo **header.php**

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires");
require_once 'config.php'; 
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
```

Luego esta **Cl/user.php**

```
public function login( array $data )
    {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
        if( !empty( $data ) ){

            // Trim all the incoming data:
            $trimmed_data = array_map('trim', $data);

            // escape variables for security
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['email'] );
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['password'] );
            $rango = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['rango'] );

            if((!$email) || (!$password) ) {
                throw new Exception( LOGIN_FIELDS_MISSING );
            }
            $password = md5( $password );
            $query = "SELECT user_id, name, email, rango, created FROM users where email = '$email' and password = '$password' ";
            $result = mysqli_query($this->_con, $query);
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            mysqli_close($this->_con);
            if( $count == 1){
                $_SESSION = $data;
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                return true;
            }else{
                throw new Exception( LOGIN_FAIL );
            }
        } else{
            throw new Exception( LOGIN_FIELDS_MISSING );
        }
    }
```

Para verificar que sea diferente redirección tengo estos valores en la base de datos
[image: Tabla users]

Existen 3 tipos de Rangos: **3 = Admin** / **2 = Editor** / **1 = Usuario**

Cada uno debe tener una redirección diferente.

Dejo por la dudas el **config.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'messages.php';

//site specific configuration declartion
define( 'BASE_PATH', 'http://localhost/');
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '');
define( 'DB_NAME', 'login');

function __autoload($class)
{
    $parts = explode('_', $class);
    $path = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$parts);
    require_once $path . '.php';
}
```

Probe usando el siguiente codigo:

```
if($_SESSION['rango'] == "3"
```

Pero me tira error de null.

Desde ya agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Estás haciendo siempre un `session_start();` antes de leer o modificar `$_SESSION`? Porque en `login()` no lo veo, salvo que esté en otro lado.

Comment: Hola Azeos y gracias por tu respuesta, ya he probado con login() pero me tira null, o no me redirecciona a ningún lado.

Comment: No veo donde asignar a `$_SESSION['rango']` su valor. Pero se entiende lo que te digo? Para hacer uso de `$_SESSION` antes tenés que hacer un `session_start()`. Dentro de `login()` veo que estás usando `$_SESSION`, pero no veo ningún `session_start()` lo estás haciendo?

Comment: No, en eso estoy fallando. Aunque es seguro hacerlo?

Comment: A qué te referís con "seguro"? Si querés usar $_SESSION` no te queda otra. Si la pregunta es si es seguro guardar el rango del usuario en una sesión para validar su acceso... no lo se. Existe el "Session Hijacking".

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya lo he podido resolver. Dejo la solución en la publicación.